# What is missing to make integral Cauchy Schwartz inequality an equality

Tags: analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The Cauchy Schwartz inequality for integrals on a bounded domain reads
\begin{align}
 \int_{-a}^{a}  f^2(x) dx
 \geq 
 \frac{1}{2a}\left(\int_{-a}^a  f(x) dx \right)^2
\end{align}
Can the difference be expressed using only $\int_{-a}^a f(x)dx$ terms? If not is such an approximation possible?

Comment: Notice $$\int_{-a}^a f^2(x) dx-\frac{1}{2a}\left[\int_{-a}^a  f(x) dx\right]^2
= \int_{-a}^a \left[f(x) - \frac{1}{2a}\int_{-a}^a  f(x) dx\right]^2 dx$$
For Lebesgue integral, in order for your inequality to be an equality, $f(x)$ need to equal to the average almost everywhere. For Riemann integral over continuous $f(x)$, the condition reduces to $f(x)$ is a constant function.

Comment: Thank you for the useful notice! The above is basically $\langle f^2 \rangle \geq \langle f \rangle^2$ where $\langle \cdot \rangle$ is the average over $2a$. I was hoping for some approximation that allows to get the square out of the average. E.g., if $f$ would be symmetric at $x=0$, then I could attempt a Taylor approximation around this point.